# How to form a string using list comprehension?

Tags: python, string, list-comprehension

I am trying to form a string using a list.

If the list only has a single element e.g. `l = [10]` then the string should be `10`.

If there are multiple elements e.g. `l = [10,20,30]` then the string should be `10,20,30`.

I tried but it always appends extra `,` at the end.

```
"".join("%s," % x for x in l)
```

This produces `10,` and `10,20,30,` for the above lists.

Comment: Then throw away the last character of that string with `[:-1]`, i.e. `"".join("%s," % x for x in l)[:-1]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use the following:

`','.join(str(n) for n in l)`

Comment: To people reading this and using a different separator character than `,`, you can replace that with any other string (ex. `'--'.join(...)`) or even an empty string (ex. `''.join(..)`).

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution. I do not know if it satisfies your

```
str(l)[1:-1]
```

Comment: This will work with some change str(l)[1:-1].replace(" ", "")